# Assigning numeric value to array unexpected token "["

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

Uhg, I really hate asking this as I am sure I've missed it somewhere in search.

im learning JS (pure) and I know several languages, however while this assigning is legal in many I use, for some reason in js it being problematic.

```
    var gear = []; // global assignment

    gear[0]=200; // this is an error here

    function bla(){

        gear[0] = 200;// putting in a function is also an error
    }

// the above causes an unexpected token "[" error. Even BASIC allows this.
```

So doing some searching I found the placement of the assignment is wrong, so I've tried it global, I've tried it inside a function, it always comes up with an error.

so the questions I have (as far as pure js) can you not assign a numerica value to an array?
Where can I put this?
if I am assigning this wrong (which I sure I am) how can I get index 0 to equal some value?
Should I be using parenthesis?
My whole program which is working really well until I went to clean up the coded to add some arrays. And now it's stuck on this token. (I could write it as a console AP, but prefer a web base)

thanks guys!

Comment: I do not have any error here when using your code. Can you replicate the issue in a snippet?

Comment: working fine for me too

Answer (score -1):

OK, I did some checking.. NONE of what I was questioning was the answer.
Apparently when I am initializing the variable, I forgot that I did this, so when I go to assign it a value, it gets that error:

example:

```
var gear = []; // setup the array this is fine
gear[0] = 200; // this IS fine as well, but....

var gear[0] = 200;// is what I found further in the code, which in turn triggered the error.
```

Normally this is fine, if the original

```
var gear = [];
```

did not exist. That was confusing. Js seems to let you just randomly "var" stuff around the in code (coding standards not withstanding).

I am more comfortable with php, which is pretty loose language, so this problem is rarely if ever encountered. Same with pascal, basic (unless you turn on OPTION EXPLICIT), to name a 
few.